# React & Axios - Not receiving response data upon page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Working on a project here and ran into an issue. I haven't had this problem before but now I do for some reason.

So I am making an GET request to ASOS API, but it is acting very strange. Some of these, such as `name` is received upon page refresh, but mainly the other things like information about the `brand` becomes undefined. Now, the brand is in another object inside of the API. But I have had other things at other parts of the page before that were also in objects. But I did not have any issue there.

Here is how the API call looks like:
[image]

And here is my code for the API fetch:

```
const FetchAPI = (props) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const [brand, setBrand] = useState({});
  const [price, setPrice] = useState({});

  const [params, setParams] = useState({
    id: "23363645",
    lang: "en-US",
    store: "US",
    sizeSchema: "US",
    currency: "USD",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://asos2.p.rapidapi.com/products/v3/detail",
      params: params,
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "",
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        setProduct(response.data);
        setBrand(response.data.brand);
        setPrice(response.data.price.current);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Product
        name={product.name}
        price={price.text}
        brand={brand.description.replace( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '')}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am sending the data over to `Product` which is the product page of the item I am requesting. But whenever I refresh the page, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`. I did remove replace, and it worked fine. And if I placed replace back into the `brand.description` and saved, still worked fine. But on the page refresh, it crashes.

Is it perhaps trying to load my `return` before the `useEffect`? If so, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that while data from API is being fetched, brand.description is undefined and there is no replace method on undefined. You can either do this - >

```
<div>
  <Product
    name={product.name}
    price={price.text}
    brand={brand.description ? brand.description.replace( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '') : ""}
  />
</div>
```

or

```
const [brand, setBrand] = useState({ description: ""});
```

and keep the remaining code same.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, unrelated to your question, you have many superfluous state variables. You have `product` which stores all the data of the product and then `price` and `brand` which stores subsets of the same data.
Consider using only the `product` state variable, or if you want to keep the names do something like

```
const price = product.price.current;
```

Second, your default value for `brand` is an empty object, meaning `brand.description` is `undefined`.

You can solve this with optional chaining like so:

```
 <Product
        name={product?.name}
        price={price?.text}
        brand={brand?.description?.replace( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '')}
      />
```

Comment: Ahh okay, I see.. And yes, I have a lot of state variables but will change that. Thank you!

Comment: The idea of optional chaining is to shortCircuit to undefined so that we can return alternate values. In this case all the props for the Product component will be undefined.  So the correct way to use this is `name={product?.name || ''}` .

Answer (score 0):

useEffect gets called only after the component is rendered . So when the component is rendered for the first time you have the state brand as an empty object . So what you are trying to do is {}.description -> . This is undefined .

This is the reason why its a good practice to always have a loading state when the component is making an api call.

```
const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);

const getProductDetails = async() => {

  const options = {
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://asos2.p.rapidapi.com/products/v3/detail",
  params: params,
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-key": "",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "",
  },
 };
 try {
   const { data } = await axios.request(options);
   setProduct(data);
   setBrand(data.brand);
   setPrice(data.price.current);
  }
 catch(error){
   console.log(error)
 } finally {
   setLoading(false)
 }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getProductDetails();
  }, []);

if(loading)
  return <p> Loading ... </p>

return (
  // return your JSX here
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect hook gets called once the component is rendered so in this case initially when your API is not called your brand.description will be undefined and when you are trying to use replace on undefined the error is coming. So you can always add a check using optional chaining(?.) so even if we don't get the description in the brand it will not break the website and you should also use a loader till the API call is through.

```
<div>
  <Product
    name={product.name}
    price={price.text}
    brand={brand.description?.replace( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '')}
  />
</div>
```